# Compiling of CV does work on one machine but not other and gives a Missing number error

Tags: compiling, cv

I am trying to compile a CV on my laptop, which is not working. The file is compiling fine on a different machine, which is why I figured it must be something with the installation. I tried the following so far:
1) Using the Miktex-Console, update all packages as Admin and as User
2) Re-install TexStudio and MikTex (and update again)

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.22 and Miktex 2.9 on Windows 10.

Here is a minimal example (still including all packages of the original file):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\geometry{a4paper,left=19mm,right=20mm, top=14mm, bottom=18mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{CV} 

\setlength{\parindent}{4pt}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\textwidth}      \centering
    \Huge{\textsc{Curriculum Vitae}}
    \\
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \LARGE{\textsc{Firstname Lastname}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.9cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.9\baselineskip}

\section{Section-Test}

\begin{CV}
    \item[since 2013] I doing something great
    \item[since 2018] Something even better
\end{CV}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\noindent
City, \today

\end{document}
```

This is the part of the log-file, that shows the error (I hope, I have not much experience reading a log file):

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.42    \item
           [since 2013] I doing something great
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.42    \item
           [since 2013] I doing something great
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You're missing `\documentclass{}` at the beginning of your code

Comment: If you type `\documentclass{article}` it compiles in my computer using TeXLive

Comment: Hello Theresa and welcome to T.SE. As pointed out by others, you need to specify the `\documentclass{}` at the beginning. Also, the error seems to indicate that the `\item[xx-xx]` only accepts numbers inside the brackets and is complaining about that. Not familiar with the CV package. I mostly use `moderncv` myself. If you're still getting problems, check the documentation for the `cv` package on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/cv

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a copy-paste mistake, of course I have \documentclass[a4paper]{article} at the top. If I change to "\item[2018-2019] I doing something great" I still get the same error. The documentation is, unfortunately, really small. As I said, it compiles on other machines perfectly, so I wonder if it is anything about the installation.

Comment: I found a workaround: If you take the content of the .sty-file and put it in the header, it compiles just fine. I don't really understand why, so far, but maybe it helps some else in the future. :) Thank you all for looking into the problem!

Comment: The `.sty` for which package? or for the article class?